# Access private member from privileged method

Tags: javascript

Why cant I access the Ball objects private memebers in the draw() function? When I log them, the private variables get undefined. Shouldnt privileged methods be able to access private members?

```
var ctx;

(function () {
    console.log("Hello world!");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var ball1 = new Ball();
    ball1.draw();

})();

function Ball() {
    var that = this; // for private methods

    var posY      = 50;
    var posX      = 50;
    var velocityX = 0;
    var velocityY = 0;
    var radius    = 10;

    this.draw = function () {
        console.log(this.posY); // outputs 'undefined'
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
        ctx.arc(this.posX, this.posY, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: they are local variables, not part of the object. Drop `this` so it will be `console.log(posY);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define them with `var` so they are *"private"*, they are not going to be in the `this` *scope*. Drop `this` and just reference the variables and it will work.

```
var ctx;

(function () {
    console.log("Hello world!");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var ball1 = new Ball();
    ball1.draw();

})();

function Ball() {
    var that = this; // for private methods

    var posY      = 50;
    var posX      = 50;
    var velocityX = 0;
    var velocityY = 0;
    var radius    = 10;

    this.draw = function () {
        console.log(posY); 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
        ctx.arc(posX, posY, r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks! but could it be any problems(reference error things) with this approach? for ex if I create multiple balls with ex posY from a param?

Answer (score 0):

`this.` is needed  I believe :

```
this.posY      = 50;
this.posX      = 50;
this.velocityX = 0;
this.velocityY = 0;
this.radius    = 10;
```

(without `var`)